# Best way to store and access a lot of constants

Tags: java, class, constants

When making a game for example I have a lot of constants I would like to store. I would also like a lot of classes to be able to access these constants. What would be the best way to store and access all these values. Currently, I just store final values in a separate class and then create an instance of the class storing the constants. And to access the values I would do "objectName.nameOfConstant". So my question is, is their a formal way to store all these constants or a better way.

Comment: [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) might be of interest to you.

Comment: Don't store constants on an instance. Constants should be static.

Comment: Thanks, will look into enums. Also thanks for the recommendation with the using static, but won't I run into static to non-static reference?

Comment: Properties files or resource bundles, constants seldom are...

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to have a class with static properties, so you don't need to create the instance. e.g.:

```
public class Status {

 public static final String ACTIVE = "ACTIVE";
 public static final String INACTIVE = "INACTIVE";}
```

It can be called directly: Status.ACTIVE or Status.INACTIVE

Second possible solution is using Enum.

```
public enum Status {
  ACTIVE, INACTIVE;
}
```

Using static String is easy, but there is no type check. For example when you want to put the constant as method input parameter:

```
public void process(String input, String status)
```

When using enum

```
public void process(String input, Status status)
```

Enum will make sure your input is from the enum list. While static String can't check it, so the user of the method can put any value in the "status", and you need to make sure the method will not break if the value is something unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using an Interface to store constance values in it.

At first it may seems strange, but the interface provide many useful default settings to store const variables, such as

- final value by default
- static and public access by default
- does not need class instance

see below code example

```
public interface OlympicMedal
{
  String GOLD = "Gold";
  String SILVER = "Silver";
  String BRONZE = "Bronze";
}

//some other file
import static xx.OlympicMedal;

public class OlympicAthlete 
{
  ...
  public static boolean isWinner(String medal) {
    return OlympicMedal.GOLD.equals(medal);
  }
}
```

** **Important note** : you should *NOT* use Const interface in an inheritance way (see code below), which is known as the interface pattern and is consider a poor practice

```
public class OlympicAthlete implements OlympicMedal  // NOT recommended
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Storing constants in an interface is a bad design and should be avoided at all costs. Interfaces are meant to define a type/contract and constants are nowhere close to that.